# Relation between postgres and pg-admin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

can any one help me with this?
How pg-admin is used with postgresql?
How do they work together?
I want to know the working and the realtion between the two.

Comment: The PostgreSQL is a database engine implementing SQL standards. It usually listen as a server on a network tcp port to provide its abilities.

The pgAdmin is a sort of client. You are able to manipulate schema and data on an instance or multiple instances of PostgreSQL engines.

Comment: pgAdmin is just one of many [SQL clients](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients) that work with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin is a GUI client specifically written for PostgreSQL. It is written in Python and uses the PostgreSQL C library `libpq` via psycopg2 to communicate with the PostgreSQL database server.

You need the PostgreSQL server running before you can connect to it with pgAdmin.

pgAdmin is an independent project, and it is written by different people than PostgreSQL (although there are naturally overlaps).